# Is it possible to have a situation in which velocity of the particle is never 0 but its average velocity in an interval is 0?

Tags: kinematics, applied-physics

My book states that-" It is not possible to have a situation in which speed of the particle is never 0 but the average speed in an interval is 0"
I would like to know if the same holds true for velocity?

Comment: If you remind the speed is a scalar quantity and the velocity is a vector quantity, you will find the answer by yourself.

Comment: Look at this equation for the average velocity $\overline {\nu }=\dfrac {1}{n}\sum ^{n}_{i}\dfrac {\Delta s_{i}}{\Delta t_{i}}$ delta t and delta s are always positive, so you never get average velocity equal zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speed is the magnitude of velocity and hence must always be a positive quantity.
This means that the distance travelled, $\displaystyle \int_{t_{\rm initial}} ^{t_{\rm final}} v\,dt$ must always be positive and so the time average $\displaystyle \dfrac {\displaystyle \int_{t_{\rm initial}} ^{t_{\rm final}} v\,dt}{\displaystyle \int_{t_{\rm initial}} ^{t_{\rm final}} \,dt}$ must always be positive.

If the motion is such that the total displacement, $\displaystyle \int_{t_{\rm initial}} ^{t_{\rm final}} \vec v\,dt$, is zero, with the speed never being zero, then the average velocity is also zero.
Uniform circular motion is an example where the velocity is never zero but after a period the total displacement is zero and hence so is the average velocity.

Answer (score 1):

If you end up where you started, your average velocity will be zero over that time frame:

```
v = dx/dt
```

For the average speed, you would want the path length over time. If you've left your original position, even to return, your path length is now non-zero, so you've got an average speed of greater than zero in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, if the (1D) velocity changed continuously, then along the way of the velocity changing from positive to negative or vice versa it must have a velocity of 0 at some point due to the intermediate value theorem.

(If you were to look at 2D or 3D velocity, it can be broken up into 1D components, but the 2D or 3D velocity wouldn't necessarily have a resultant velocity of 0. In this case you could have an average velocity = 0 without instantaneous velocity = 0.)

If the (1D) velocity could change instantaneously, say from -2 m/s to 2 m/s, then you could have an average velocity of 0 m/s. It's never possible for speed to have an average of 0 (given that it can't equal 0) even if it could change instantaneously, because speed can never be negative.

Comment: "Presumably, if the velocity changed continuously, then along the way of the velocity changing from positive to negative or vice versa it must have a velocity of 0 at some point due to the intermediate value theorem." this is wrong.

Comment: What is wrong? I guess it's not generalized since I was only thinking about one dimensional velocity.

Comment: Yes. It's a 1D answer in a 3D world.

Comment: Also, this part "It's never possible for speed to have an average of 0 even if it could change instantaneously because speed can never be negative - it's a scalar." is wrong. Scalars can be negative, like the gravitational potential. 
 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/207477/why-can-scalars-have-a-sign

Comment: Ah, my bad, I accepted your edit.

Comment: @MikeSperry I don't see how that's wrong... If the value of velocity in some direction goes between -2 m/s and 2 m/s without a discontinuity, then there indeed _must_ be 0 velocity in between at some point in that direction.  It's not wrong at all, that's the IVT.  Also, yes it's incorrect to say scalars cannot be negative; but removing the whole paragraph was not appropriate.  Speed can never be negative, so a majority of what was said was correct.  Your edit really seems to have done more harm than good.

Comment: @highm I would honestly suggest rolling back the edit.  A lot of the criticism of your answer was actually incorrect, and you removed a lot of useful and relevant information by accepting that edit.  Your interpretation of the IVT is correct when considering velocity in one direction in an inertial frame.  Scalars can be negative, but you were correct in saying speed cannot be.

Comment: JMac my criticism is spot on. The first part of the answer was for 1d only. In the second part it was incorrectly started that a scalar can't be negative. The answer, as edited, removes those very real problems with the original answer.

Comment: @MikeSperry How would a "2D" or "3D" velocity which goes from positive velocity to negative velocity be able to avoid 0 velocity?  And again, just because a _scalar_ can't be negative, doesn't make it appropriate to remove everything about _speed_ not being negative, because that part was still very true.  You removed an entire paragraph because a sentence was wrong.

Comment: I guess I see what you’re saying, but it would still have made more sense to just add in that he was talking about velocity components instead of deleting it all.

Comment: @jmac ultimately, it looks like Hiram fixed up the answer which is for the best. Nice.

Comment: @MikeSperry That’s still not a good reason to remove most of their answer.  Edits really aren’t intended for such large changes.  If there’s that much wrong, leave a comment explaining why and a downvote if you feel it’s warranted.

Comment: @jmac I left comments and an edit. Hiram accepted the edits and then revised his answer. Hopefully now you understand the substantial problems I was addressing. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @MikeSperry Still, I suggest reading some of this meta discussion regarding substantial edits on answers. https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6010/correcting-incorrect-answers It's something which should be avoided in general, even if the user was okay with it in this case.

Comment: @MikeSperry I'm allowed to make mistakes in comments, and I'm allowed to question things.  I'm not going to refrain from questioning things when I don't understand the motivations behind them.  That's counterproductive to understanding and building a knowledge base.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97473/discussion-between-mike-sperry-and-jmac).